# Dynamically set values of objects added via Silverstripe GridField (CMS)

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I have a basic relation editor `GridField`, and I need to dynamically define/set the value of any objects added via that `GridField`, with data related to the `GridField`'s context.

```
class Draw extends DataObject {

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Items' => 'Item'
    );
}
```

When an Item is added via `Draw`'s `Items` `GridField`, I need to define a value for use in `Item::getCMSFields()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good suggestions in here: https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/data-model-questions/show/21517?start=7

You can work directly with the `GridField`'s `GridFieldDetailForm` component, and set fields accordingly.

The code that worked for me is:

```
    $config = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
    if($this->exists()) {
        // Ensure that fields are generated with knowledge of the parent
        $editComponent = $config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDetailForm');
        $item = new Item();
        $item->DrawID = $this->ID;
        $editComponent->setFields($item->getCMSFields());
    }
    $items = new GridField('Items', 'Items', $this->Items(), $config);
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $items);
```

You can then call `Draw::get()->byID($this->DrawID)` from `Item::getCMSFields()`

Comment: GridFieldDetailForm::setItemEditFormCallback() is the proper solution as shown by Loz in the same forum post.